# curl progress in dialog

Tags: tar, curl, dialog

how can i properly display the curl progress in the dialog window?

```
curl http://mysite.corp/image/root_21.tar.bz2 | tar -C /mnt/dest/ -jxf -
```

[image]

i tried this command but as you can see it does not display it correctly.

```
curl -f -x '' -L http://mysite.corp/image/root_21.tar.bz2 | tar -C /mnt/dest -xjpf - --exclude='dev/*' | dialog --backtitle "dialog" --stderr --title 'Linux Image' --textbox /tmp/log 30 80
```

[image]

this command almost helps me but i want it to overwrite itself and not show me new line progress in each line. basically i want it to be the same as the original command shows it but in the dialog.

```
(curl -f -x '' -L http://mysite.corp/image/root_21.tar.bz2  | tar -C /mnt/dest -xjpf - --exclude='dev/*' ) 2>&1 | dialog  --progressbox 20 120
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--progressbox` option of dialog like

```
(curl ... | tar ... ) 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 30 120
```

`2>&1` redirects the stderr output of `curl` and `tar` to the stdin,
i.e. the pipe to `dialog`.

The rewriting of lines (control char: CR  '\r' (carriage return))
is not supported by `dialog` therefore you get each progress
change in an extra line.

Comment: almost . i get the output ok now but every progress shows on a new line. in some point it push the title up so i cant see it. i need it to overwrite itself with the new line progress and not show me new line on each progress. basically i need the output the exactly as the original command will show it.

Comment: @AsafMagen I extended my answer, the feature you want is not implemented in `dialog`. Basically this is a new question how to get this (you probably need to rewrite/emulate dialog).

Comment: ok thanks you for explaining. i hope maybe someone will supply some sort of a workaround if there is any...

Answer (score 0):

When downloading with curl and redirecting to **tar**, a simple progress can be printed with:

> --checkpoint[=NUMBER]  display progress messages every NUMBERth record
>
> --checkpoint-action=ACTION   execute ACTION on each checkpoint

For example, this will download and extract gz file, while printing dot every 10 check-points:

```
curl -s -L $url | tar -xz --checkpoint=.10
```

To see more details during progress:

- Remove the "-s" from the curl command, if you don't want curl to have "silent" output.
- Add "-v" to the tar command, to print list of files being extracted from the archive.